# Stored procedure in SQL Server for backend

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm beginner in SQL Server. I have two tables, `User` and `User_role`.

I send user name & password from ASP.NET Api to SQL Server.

I need a procedure that gets user name & pass from `tbluser` and returns `PostId` from `tblRole`.

I could do it with Entity Framework, but I should get it by a procedure
and don't know anything about that.

Thanks a lot

| id | username | password |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | person1 | 123 |
| 11 | person1 | 123 |
| 12 | person1 | 123 |

| id | postId | userId | roleId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 11 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 12 | 2 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just return the `postId`, you can try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE st_getPostIdFromRole(
       @username varchar(100), 
       @password varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT PostId
   FROM User_Role ur
   INNER JOIN Users u ON (u.Id = u.UserId)
   WHERE u.UserName = @username
   AND   u.Password = @password
END
```

PS:- I sincerely hope that this is just a learning project and you are not storing passwords as plaintext or hashing them without a salt.

Comment: thanx a lot  ; yes i have a salt & hashPs just for example write that thanx a looooot  :)